# MVC4 and Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a single controller and view working that calls a web service, and returns a result. At the moment, it's my default controller, called Home, and it uses the Index view page.

It's working. I can post data and then put something on the refreshed screen. It reloads the same view.

Now, once I submit, and I get a good reply, I want to load a different controller/view.

My routes look like this right now:

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Home",
        "{lang}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", lang="English" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Location",
        "{lang}",
        new { controller = "Location", action = "Index", lang = "English" });
```

I created a controlled called Location, and it just has this:

```
 //LocationController 
 public class LocationController : Controller
 {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       return View();
    }
 }
```

In my home controller, I am doing the logic, and then attempting to load the new page.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HomeModel model)
        {
            var proxy = new Proxy();
            var r = proxy.GetLocationByAddress(model.SearchString, o.ToString());
            if(r==null)
            {
                ViewBag.Error = "Error during search";
                return View(model);
            }
            ViewBag.Error = string.Format("Found {0} at {1}, {2}", r.StreetName, r.Latitude, r.Longitude);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Location");

        }
```

But when I run it, submit it, step through, it hits the RedirectToAction - but ... the Home screen simply refreshes. I never see the new Location view. What am I doing wrong here? I have't grasped Routes yet... I need to pass a new object to the Location.Index screen to display...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route mapping is incorrect, check this out: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Location",
    "Location/{lang}",
    new { controller = "Location", action = "Index", lang = "English" });
```

Comment: Rob, I tried this, but the default start screen is reloaded. What's starnge is the the ''return View()' in the Location controller is run - but the wrong view is returned...

Comment: Ah, wait... I removed the other routes, and this works. THhanks.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so you need to make any changes. As in your case you want to load different controller with its respecting view you need below change only

replace this code `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Location");`

with this code  `return Redirect("http://www.yoursite.com/Location/Index");`

Your change is like redirection from one page to another therefore you need to put your complete path here

please try & reply if any problem